# Can I edit session context in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a web app that allows users to edit configuration tables in my database.

For audit purposes, I would like to capture the user_name of the authenticated user rather than the account that the web app uses to execute the queries.

Previously my database was on MSSQL. We could pass the user_name into context_info and the trigger will then reflect the user's user_name.

Is there a way to achieve similar results on Snowflake? I have explored Streams + Query_history but that only tells me that a query was fired through the web app account.

Comment: [Query History View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) isn't good enough?

Comment: Just to be clear about terminology, in Snowflake an Account is the top-level object in your relationship with Snowflake (the bit specific to you in your Snowflake URL). I assume you have configured your app to connect via a single user, regardless of the user logged into the app? You may be able to set something up with the QUERY_TAG session parameter - but that would be set when you make the connection or by issuing an ALTER SESSION command so may not be practicable depending on how your code is structured.

Comment: Yup it is like what @NickW mentioned. Query tag looks promising and I'll relook at the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake captures all queries executed and users can view those queries via either
the `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY` view or via the information_schema
(e.g. `information_schema.query_history_by_user`).

If your web app is using a single Snowflake user (sometimes called service accounts, or batch ids, or similar),
and you need to find out what queries "application end users" are causing your single service account to execute,
I'd suggest leveraging Snowflake's "query tags" for this.

To leverage query tags, simply execute a command like the following, before each query or set of queries performed by your application, by your service account, on behalf of the end user.

```
ALTER SESSION 
SET QUERY_TAG = '{"application":"Awesome Web App", "endUser":"Rich Murnane"}';
```

Note: You don't need to use JSON, but I think it's cool  :-)

Once you start logging your queries performed by end users,
you can find out what end users are doing by querying by the `QUERY_TAG` field in the `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY` view, or the `information_schema query_history/query_history_by*` table functions.

Links:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-session.html